# Why do my resource caps continuously increase slowly?

Tags: kittens-game

I noticed this my last run too.  I'm late in my current run, working on stockpiling Eludium.  I have engineers crafting plate, steel, and parchment/manuscript/compendium/blueprints.  I am not crafting ships or anything else, and I'm not running any additional scripts.

When I went to bed last night I had ~45k max gold, 32k max faith, and ~178k max titanium.  This morning my caps are now ~62k max gold, ~44k max faith, and ~231k max titanium.

What mechanism is making these values slowly increase?

---

## Update

In the interest of troubleshooting this, here is an export of my kittens game (link removed).  If anyone is interested, they are welcome to load it up and leave it running for a day or two to see if they experience the same thing.

The resource caps are currently:

- Titanium: 231.06K
- Gold: 62.87K
- Faith: 45.09K

---

## Update 2

After leaving it running over thanksgiving, none of my resources went up, so apparently I'm doing *something*, I'm just not sure what.  Thanks to everyone who looked into this, and especially Oliver Salzburg, who correctly pointed out that there was nothing in the code that would slowly increase the caps.

Comment: None of the resources you're engineering have an impact on the storage cap. I'm actually not aware of anything that would slowly increase the mentioned storage caps over time. I've also reviewed the source and, other than buildings and upgrades, I couldn't see other parameters affecting the storage caps.

Comment: Well it's definitely happening. The rate of increase seems to go down over time, based on how my last run went. In my last run, I had stopped building storage facilities, but every day or two I would be able to buy an additional trade post or mint, etc, and then I would be back in the state where the next building cost more than my capacity

Comment: My best guess is that there is an upgrade or an expansion that is not being taken into account until you reload the game.

Comment: Gold and titanium will slowly increase if you (automatically) craft trade ships. But according to your save export you aren't crafting trade ships automatically. And this wouldn't have any effect on your max faith either.

Comment: Do you have the Order of the Void metaphysics upgrade? That passively praises and if you also have Solar Revolution, that could be it...

Comment: I have it on my current run, but not in previous runs where this still happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun Alter (Every temple improves happiness by 0.5%) also gives a large increase to faith capacity through some unlisted mechanic.

For example, buying sun alter again (level 8) just increased my faith capacity from around ~305k to ~350k.

Answer (score 1):

Reactor Vessel -> Harbor feedback loop?

Comment: Nope. It seems to be one of the order of the sun religious upgrades (NOT golden spire), but I'm not sure which one. It's very repeatable though. I'll buy one of them, then come back later and my faith cap is higher.  Whichever it is gives a bigger boost than golden spire does.  By any chance are you THE bloodrizer?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most likely scenario is that you passed a **millennium**.

This grants you 1 paragon and paragon have a direct effect on your storage space.

Comment: I'm only at about year 300

Comment: @masconejos Then I am thoroughly confused and am awaiting the proper answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible explanation for the titanium cap.

If we assume that you had the Numerology metaphysics upgrade, and that most of your storage was due to cryostations, we can solve for the following numbers:

- Titanium storage due to cryostations: 176.7k
- Titanium storage due to everything else: 19k
- Baseline storage: 195.7k
- During Helios, cryostation storage is minus 10%; 178k
- During Terminus, cryostation storage is plus 20%; 231k

The numbers are not terribly plausible, but could work out, if you didn’t have many harbours or much paragon at that point. You can check, if you kept your save from back then.